# Large Data Structure and Program Dumps

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I am using an SDK provided by a vendor for a REST service.  In order to use the SDK, I pass several Data Structures.  Some of these Data Structures are Array Data Structures with arrays as subfields, some are just Array Data Structures, and some are just plain old Data Structures.  For example, one Array Data Structure is defined with a Dim(3750) and several subfields defined with a Dim(10).  Another is just defined as an Array Data Structure with Dim(3750).  As a visual, it would look like this:

```
D DS1                     Dim(3750)
D  subfield1      10A     Dim(10)
D  subfiled2       7  4   Dim(10)

D DS2                     Dim(3750)
D  subfield1      40A
D  subfield2      15  4
```

There are way more subfields but I am just trying to provide a brief visual.  We have subprocedures that contain parameters that mirror DS1 and DS2.  I wrote a Service Program to act as a front-end to the vendor's SDK that uses parameters defined with likeds(DS1) and likeds(DS2) just so I can pass back what is returned from the SDK without having to do a lot of coding. Another Developer wrote subprocedures that are in a copybook to parse what is returned in the Data Structures in order to feed information to our ERP package.  Again, the parameters to the subprocedures are defined using likeds.

The norm for our programs is to produce a program dump when something goes awry.  This is the default behavior of the vendor's ERP and since we modify some of their programs and adopt some of their standards, it also becomes our norm.  Since adding code to our own custom programs and modified version of the ERP vendor's programs to make use of this new REST service, if something goes awry, it takes forever to produce a program dump and we usually have to answer a message where we've reached the max spool file pages for the program dump.  Usually, we just answer NOMAX and move on.

Hopefully, that is enough background and now we can get to my issue.  The issue is that we now have program dumps that can be up to 9,000+ pages after the message is answered.  I am assuming this is due to all the large Array Data Structures in our various subprocedures.  We are currently in test mode and I am trying to come up with a solution to address the large program dumps.  Some of the programs that this REST service was added to are time sensitive and if the program sits in MSGW for a bit, it will delay other jobs waiting behind it and then we get a snowball effect and I, or someone on my team, gets a call in the middle of the night or it's an interactive job that takes forever to end because it is writing out a 5,000 page program dump and the user gets impatient and closes out instead of waiting.  The result will be the same, someone will be asking us to fix it and quickly.  Any thoughts on how I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility, that would reduce the size of the dumps, would be to move the procedures in the copybook into a separate module. Or even into a service program, if they are copied into more than one program.

Comment: Thanks, @BarbaraMorris.  The Developer that was responsible for this bit of coding decided to use copybooks. I will pass your suggestion along.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using OVRPRTF to override printer file QPPGMDMP with MAXRCDS(*NOMAX).

Comment: I will check with my iSeries Admin to see if this is a possibility.  Sometimes they are a little...particular...when it comes to *NOMAX on spool files.

Answer (score 0):

IMO...If program dumps are routine enough to cause problems...then you've got other more serious problems.

If you're still relying on a job going to MSGW and being answered manually, you've got yet another problem.

Your program, particularly a web service program,  should gracefully handle any reasonably possible error.

Global error handling should take care of everything else, dumping the program, saving the job log and notifying your team.

Read through chapter 7, *Exception and error handling*, in the [Who Knew You Could Do That with RPG IV?](https://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg245402.html?Open) IBM Redbook.

Comment: Charles, I think the issue of a MSGW due to the system asking whether to print more lines in the dump listing is different from a MSGW due to an inquiry message due to an exception.

Comment: @BarbaraMorris,  no argument.  But it as I read it, the job's initial MSGW waits to be manually answered.  That's a problem IMHO.  He could always change QPPGMDMP to be *NOMAX to take care of the size of the dump.

Comment: @Charles, I apologize for the confusion.  First, program dumps are not routine for us.  I am trying to plan ahead if a program dump should occur.  We can try and plan for common things, which I do, but eventually, some unhandled exception occurs.  Barbara Morris is correct in that the program is not sitting in MSGW due to an unhandled exception.  It is when standard error handling fails and global error handling produces a program dump spool file that reaches the maximum spool file pages.  I appreciate the Redbook suggestion.  I have read some of it but will read again to see what I've missed.